# Excel - Copy last value of the cell above if condition is met

Tags: vba, excel

I want to fill empty cells on column H (CODIGO) with the last value above, but only if column B (DR) is empty, like this:

[image: RegistroPROYECTOS]

I have to do this in four different spreadsheets with approx. 1200-2000 rows, so I can't go one by one..

Comment: To be clear, are you calling an Excel spreadsheet a database? Or are you trying to update an actual Access database?

Comment: I'm calling an Excel spreadsheet a database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using

```
Public Sub FillBlanks()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim c As Range

    With ActiveSheet
        Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row, "H"))
    End With

    For Each c In rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks)
        If IsEmpty(c.Offset(0, Columns("B").Column - c.Column)) Then c.Value2 = c.Offset(-1, 0).Value2
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your time. When I run this I get the error 1004, should I change something in function of my spreadsheet? On the real one, the column A of my example is named "DR" and is in B, and the column B of the example is named "CODIGO" and is the column H.

Comment: This is why people don't like helping when you give a very limited example. You've given us one example. Then said your actual data structure is completely different. No wonder its erred.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know if you want to keep helping me, nothing happens, there is no error code or message, I changed the question with real spreadsheet..

Comment: That was my mistake - it was still pointed at column `A`. Updated again